# Excel VBA, Facing some issues

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
For Search_Library = 0 To 200
    j = Search_Library * 20
    If Worksheets("Config Algemeen").Range("H2").offset(Search_Config, 0).Value = Worksheets("Library").Range("A2").offset(j, 0).Value Then
        For k = 1 To 200
            l = k * 2
            For m = 0 To 19
                MyChoices(m) = Worksheets("Library").Range("A2").offset(j + m, l).Value
            Next m
                With Worksheets("Config Algemeen").Range("H2").offset(Search_Config, k).Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyChoices, ",")
                End With
        Next k
    Else
        'Nothing
    End If
Next Search_Library
```

Now I'm facing a problem: I want to loop through "Search_Config" each time when "Search_Library" reach a value of 200 (max value). What  is the best way to loop through "Search_Config" as well? Basically I want to do add 1 (+1) to "Search_Config" and start from zero (0) with "Search_Library".

Comment: What have you tried?  It would seem simple to enclose your existing loop within a `For Search_Config = x to y … Next Search_Config` loop.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That's what I thought... But Excel seems to crash (no responce). Excel gives me an "Offset failure".

Comment: I've never seen that Excel error. and a Google search is unrevealing.  So the error must be coming from something else in your system.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Method Of Range Class Failed

Comment: That is a VBA error message. Is that the Exact message?  Usually that type of message refers to a specific method. What line causes the error?  What are the values of the different parameters in that line when the error occurs? That's some of what you need to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Nothing at all. Just a crash. Kinda anoying grrrr... method range object _worksheet failed

Comment: I don't understand your response.  I understand a crash to mean the program shuts down or freezes, so you would not get an error message.  If there is an error message, and you select the `Debug` option from the dialog, that should take you to a particular line in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Search_Config = 0 To 200
For Search_Library = 0 To 200
    j = Search_Library * 20
    If (Worksheets("Config Algemeen").Range("H2").offset(Search_Config, 0).Value = Worksheets("Library").Range("A2").offset(j, 0).Value) And Not (Worksheets("Config Algemeen").Range("H2").offset(Search_Config, 0).Value = "") Then
        For k = 1 To 200
            l = k * 2
            n = l - 1
            For m = 0 To 19
                MyChoices(m) = Worksheets("Library").Range("A2").offset(j + m, l).Value
            Next m
                With Worksheets("Config Algemeen").Range("H2").offset(Search_Config, k)
                    If Not Worksheets("Library").Cells(2 + j, 1 + n).Value = "" Then
                        .AddComment Worksheets("Library").Cells(2 + j, 1 + n).Value
                    Else
                        'Nothing
                    End If
                    If Worksheets("Library").Range("A2").offset(j, l).Value = "*VALUE*" Or Worksheets("Library").Range("A2").offset(j, l).Value = "" Then
                        'Nothing
                    Else
                        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyChoices, ",")
                    End If
                End With
        Next k
    Else
        'Nothing
    End If
Next Search_Library
Next Search_Config
```

It's working like this now. And everything seems fine. It's quick and solit as rock. Thank you for helping me! It brought me on the right track.